# Specifying random effects in GAM model with the gam package (in R)

Tags: r, random-effects-model, generalized-additive-model

I would like to set up a GAM model in R using the library **gam** (not mgcv!). I do not know how to include
random effects inside the model. The syntax of the gam package is not clear to me.

There are 8 variables which are fixed effects, *var1, ..., var8* and another two variables *R1* and *R2* which are random effects. *R1* and *R2* are categorical variables.

The model

```
library(gam)
GAM <- gam(y ~ s(var1) + s(var2) + s(var3) + s(var4) + 
        s(var5) + s(var6) + s(var7) + s(var8), 
        family = binomial, data = data_set)
```

does not contain any random effects.

How should these random effects be included in the above R code?

Answer (score 2):

With the **gam** package, you indicate random effect terms in the formula using the `random()` function:

```r
y ~ s(Age) + random(Level, lambda=1)
```

where `Level` is a factor in the `data` and `lambda` is a non-negative penalty parameter. This is interpreted as a variance ratio in a mixed effects model - namely the ratio of the noise variance to the random-effect variance.

Instead of `lambda` you can specify `df`, a desired number of degrees of freedom for the term, which allows you to specify how much shrinkage you want

```r
y ~ s(Age) + random(Level, df = 5) # Level might have 10 levels say
```

From `?gam::random` `df` is document as:

> the target equivalent degrees of freedom, used as a smoothing parameter. The real smoothing parameter (`lambda`) is found such that `df=tr(S)`, where S is the implicit smoother matrix. Values for `df` should be greater than `0` and less
> than the number of levels of `f`. If both `df` and `lambda` are supplied, the latter takes precedence. Note that `df` is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is very helpful.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.